# Preload canvas before html body?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, canvas

I have a basic webapp that uses canvas frames to render content on each webpage. On loading the page, chrome will render a single blank canvas frame before the main content is rendered (~20ms or so of blank frame).

When clicking through multiple pages, the blank frame is visually distracting and results in a bad user experience.

Is there a way to pre-render the canvas frame before chrome lays out the page? Or is there a way to have the canvas frame ready so that chrome does not display a blank frame?

The basic code outline looks like this:

```
<script>
  function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("samplecanvas");
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height,
                      0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
      img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,...........";
    } else {
      alert('canvas not supported by this browser')
    }
  }
</script>
<body  onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="samplecanvas" width="800" height="800"></canvas>
</body>
```

Like I said, the above does work, it just results in a blank frame that is really annoying. The base64 embedded image is large (720p), but I still wouldn't expect this to be slow to render.

Any ideas?

Comment: but what should the webpage display before canvas finish rendering?

Comment: A fallback image would be nice. But this doesn't seem fully supported by all browsers e.g.:

<canvas id="samplecanvas" width="800" height="800"><img ... ></canvas>

But more importantly, the rest of the page loads and looking at chrome performance tools, it's all entirely single threaded. It'd be nice if the canvas element was ready to display (maybe pre rendered in a separate thread / worker) with the rest of the page as it was parsing.